# Using cache policy "CACHE_THEN_NETWORK" adds duplicate rows in the Listview

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse query to get some data and show it int he list view. I am using cache policy `ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK` which fetches the data from cache first,then shows it in the list view, then fetches the data from the network and shows the updated data in the listView.

The problem is, when the data is fetched from the network (after fetch from cache) then duplicate rows are added to my listView. I can not simply clear the list in the adapter because i am using pagination in the listView.

My question is, is there any callback which triggers when the data is fetched from cache or network? or is there any other way round to fix the described problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding items to your list, remove the item that is already there.

```
public void addItem(YourItem item){
    for(YourItem item2 : yourItemsList){
       if(item.getObjectId().equals(item2.getObjectId()){
           yourItemsList.remove(item2);
           break;
       }
    }
    yourItemsList.add(item);
    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Better yet**, if you are subclassing `ParseObject` you can override `equals()` in your class:

```
@ParseClassName("YourItem")
public class YourItem extends ParseObject {
      /* All your accessors */

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) {
          return o != null 
                   && o instanceof YourItem 
                   && ((YourItem) o).getObjectId().equals(getObjectId());
      }
}
```

Then, you can change the `addItem` method to this:

```
public void addItem(YourItem item){
      yourItems.remove(item); //this will remove the object with matching ID if it exits.
      yourItems.add(item);
      yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, actually i was looking a bit more smarter and more efficient way of doing it, this brute-force way of comparing each item from 'yourItemList' with every 'item' from 'itemList' will surely effect performance where the list is huge (can be more than 1000 in my case).

Comment: Ultimately it will always come down to comparing each item.

Comment: I could make it a bit efficient, since the duplicated entries will always be in the end of the list, so i started checking for the duplication from the end of my itemList instead of the start, which fixed the performance problem.

Comment: Honestly, you should be clearing the cached data when you receive the network data. That would be the best performance and more accurate. If a network list deleted an item, searching for duplicates will not remove those.

Comment: Good suggestion, documentation says that sdk handles the cache clearing itself. Not sure if it handles the problem you static, but its a good catch . Thanks

Comment: The documentation mentions it will clear the cache, true. But what they mean is when the cache is full, it will clear it out. So it is managing your cache for you. So that wont affect you here. So to sum it up, I would show your cached data right off the start, then load your network data. clear the instance of your cached list and replace it with the network list.